# Fails to send cookies on http request

Tags: php, cookies, vbscript

I have vbscript code that send an ajax request to server with cookie using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object. I have read about [this bug and workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290899). By invoking `setRequestHeader` twice, cookies should properly sent..but that not happening..

The vbscript code:

```vb
Dim http 
set http =  WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.open "POST", "http://localhost/echo", false
http.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "SESSID=f3rds19k7qu58pvmb80561dc76" '1st invoke  '
http.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "SESSID=f3rds19k7qu58pvmb80561dc76" '2nd invoke  '
http.send sReq

msgbox http.responseText
```

And on server side at `http://localhost/echo/index.php` contains code

```
<?php print_r(getallheaders());?>
```

that php code basically only echoing the request header back to the client, and even I invoke twice this what I got:

```
Array
(
    [Accept] => */*
    [X-Requested-With] => XMLHttpRequest
    [Accept-Language] => id
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/4.0 (bla..bla..bla...)
    [Host] => localhost
    [Connection] => Keep-Alive
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
)
```

As you can see no cookie on the header. How to make cookie sent properly to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found solution... simple.. just use `WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest` instead of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`

```vb
Dim http 
set http =  WScript.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
http.open "POST", "http://localhost/echo", false
http.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "SESSID=f3rds19k7qu58pvmb80561dc76"

msgbox http.responseText
```