# How to send a GET method with a cookie using Microsoft.XMLHTTP

Tags: curl, vbscript

I have a VBScript script that encounters an error when executing the second curl command, which is intended to retrieve the currently active user.

```
Dim login, password, tenantID, url

login = "Joe"
password = "SECRET"
url = "example.com"

strRequest = "{""login"":""" & login & """, ""password"":""" & password & """}"
EndPointLink = "https://" & url & "/auth"

Dim http
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
http.open "POST", EndPointLink, False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
http.send strRequest

If http.Status = 200 Then
    Token = http.responseText   
    EndPointLink2 = "https://" & url & "/rest/activeUser"
    Dim http2
    Set http2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    http2.open "GET", EndPointLink2, False
    http2.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "AUTH_TOKEN=" & Token & "; TENANTID=123"
    http2.send
    If http2.Status = 200 Then
        ' response = http.responseText
        MsgBox http2.responseText
    Else
        MsgBox "ERRCODE : " & http2.status
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "ERRCODE : " & http.status
End If
```

Error message:

```
C:\wamp64\www\script\test2.vbs(26, 5) msxml3.dll: Access denied.
```

I have verified that the variable `Token` is accurate by testing it with a separate curl command, which executed successfully.

Here is the curl command that I'm referring to:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\curl\bin\curl.exe -X GET -H "Cookie: AUTH_TOKEN=123abc;TENANTID=123" https://example.com:443/rest/activeUser
```

Could you please assist me in identifying what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fails to send cookies on http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618603/fails-to-send-cookies-on-http-request)